# How can I access a newly-opened tab's window object? [in a firefox extension]

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I'm attempting to convert a Greasemonky script to an extension for Firefox and I'm trying to make my extension automatically attach a simple script to any webpage when a new tab is opened. I'm converting the script from Greasemonkey because I'd like to take advantage of advanced preferences and menu options.

I access the tab using this:

```
var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;
container.addEventListener("TabOpen", tabAdded, false);

function tabAdded(event) {
var newtabwindow = event.target.____ //I don't know what goes here
//attach script to newtabwindow
}
```

and my goal is to append the script to the document in the new tab once it loads using this function:

```
function scriptrunner(targetwindow) {
var myScript = targetwindow.content.document.createElement('script');
    myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    myScript.setAttribute('src','chrome://addonname/content/addonscript.js');
    targetwindow.content.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
}
```

This function works fine to attach the script to the current page when attached to a toolbar button with oncommand="scriptrunner(window)", but I don't know how I could access the window in the newly opened tab, or if I should cut out the window from the equation and access the document another way.

Comment: does `var newtabwindow = event.target;` not work?

Comment: From your description it seems that the Mozilla's [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/) is more suitable for that job. You can use [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) to attach content script to any web page where the URL matches a pattern, or use the [tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `contentWindow`, which is a property of the `browser` element.

Given a `tab`, call [`gBrowser.getBrowserForTab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbrowser#m-getBrowserForTab) to acquire the `browser` element associated with the `tab`. Then access either `contentDocument` or `contentWindow` property of the [`browser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser#p-contentWindow) element (these are equivalent to the `document` and `window` objects you should already be familiar with).

Also -- if I'm not mistaken -- you'll need to listen for the `"load"` event of the `contentWindow` in addition to listening to events for the `tab`.

Comment: I found that the examples for [On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/On_page_load) removed the need to listen for the TabOpen event and yes, I had to use a load event listener for the window.